# Preallocating array of a custom type

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I try to preallocate an array containing custom types. I know that for simple types such as `Int` I can simply do:

```
Array(Int, 24)
```

to preallocate an array with 24 integers. However, when I do the same for a custom type:

```
type spam
   foo
   baz
end

spam_alloc = Array(spam, 24)
24-element Array{spam,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
<snip>
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

and I cannot access any of the elements of `spam_alloc`:

```
spam_alloc[1]
ERROR: access to undefined reference
 in getindex at array.jl:277
```

So my question is how I can get this working. Or is there a better way to work with groups of custom types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of the Array are just random memory if the value is stored inline (bitstypes and immutables). If not, the objects are stored boxed, so it keeps track of which ones were assigned. This is the correct way to preallocate an array, you can assign into it just as you would with any other array:

```
spam_alloc[1] = spam(1,2)
```

Comment: You are right, you can simply assign a `spam` object to an element of `spam_alloc`, i.e. `spam_alloc[1] = spam(1,2)`.